# Error while creating the database in azure databricks using sql script, runtime exception:Unable to instantiate

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to create the database in azure databricks using sql script.

```
 %sql
    CREATE DATABASE DB_TEST;
```

failed with below error

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

Also, I have tried creating a table in default database, failed with same error.

Can someone help me on fixing the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

the error message indicates that there is an issue with the Hive Metastore client -- which is used by Databricks to manage metadata related to tables and databases

1. check if the Metastore service is running: Hive Metastore service running on your cluster
2. check the configuration: make sure that the configuration of the Metastore client is correct(check `hive-site.xml` in `/etc/hive/conf` on cluster driver node. `hive.metastore.uris` should be set to the URL of the Metastore service)
3. check the network connectivity: Make sure that there is no issue with the network connectivity between the cluster and the Metastore service(using telnet or nc command to check if you can connect to the Metastore)
4. restart the Metastore service

Answer (score 0):

You may try below options if helps:

- Use `System.setSecurityManager(null)` at start after importing `java.lang.System`
- Restarting the virtual machine or System, this should also release the lock
- Make `hive.metastore.schema.verification=false` in hive-site.xml file, this might help.
- Use `rm metastore_db/*.lck` It can be found in your `home/user` directory. You can use the `locate` command to find it: `locate metastore_db`
  After removing the lock files, close the current session. Call hive shell in new session.